# Spring boot Integration Test multimodule maven application with docker container

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a multi-module maven application which uses Spring boot. It has Rest API's defined to provide service to the consumers.

- spring boot parent

  - myproject parent (both parent and module pom)

    - module1
    - module-it (integration tests)

In my Module 1 Spring boot maven plugin configuration in pom  is as follows

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.package.Application</mainClass>
        <layout>JAR</layout>
    </configuration>
     <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal> 
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration> 
        </execution> 
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am using fabric io to create docker image. see below for fabric io plugin definition in my Module 1

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.24.0</version>           
    <configuration>         
        <images>
            <image>         
                <alias>service</alias>
                <name>Sample</name>         
                <build>         
                    <from>greyfoxit/alpine-openjdk8</from>
                    <entryPoint>
                        <exec>
                            <arg>java</arg>
                            <arg>-jar</arg>
                            <arg>maven/sample-model-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</arg>
                        </exec>
                    </entryPoint>           
                    <assembly>          
                        <descriptorRef>artifact-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </assembly>
                    <ports>
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </ports>
                </build>                        
            </image>            
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>docker-build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>                       
</plugin>
```

Added classifier configuration in Spring boot maven plugin as exec for the Integration Test module to identify the Spring boot application class to boot.

In my Integration Test module, i am using failsafe plugin to do integration test. see below for plugin definition in the integration Test module

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <groups>io.sample.test.IntegrationTest</groups>
                <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My IntegrationTest class is defined as below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class ControllerIT 
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Autowired
    private Environment env;



    @Test
    public void IntegrationTestForService() throws Exception {

        JsonNode node=mapper.readTree(new File("/src/integration-test/resources/Request.json"));
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/api/sample/v1")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(node.toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), response.getStatus());

    }
}
```

IntegrationTest is executing fine and able to test the REST API's. How ever when i try to run the docker file using docker run using the module1 jar file, spring boot is not starting. It says manifest is not found. below is the error message.

**no main manifest attribute, in maven/sample-model-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.**

When i removed the exec classifier from module 1, spring boot is able to start when docker run command is executed. However, i have problem with the execution of Integration test case with Spring boot Test if the classifier is not present.

**Could you please suggest if there is any option.**

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you're going to use the classifier to generate a separate repackaged jar for Spring Boot, then you need to reference that repackaged jar in your docker-maven-plugin configuration. That is, your `<entrypoint><exec>` should be invoking sample-model-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar. (Note the "-exec")

Also, just for good practice, you may want to consider using project variables for your jar target, rather than hardcoding the version, e.g.:

```
<entrypoint>
    <exec>
        <arg>java</arg>
        <arg>-jar</arg>
        <arg>maven/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-exec.jar</arg>
    </exec>
</entrypoint>
```

You'll also need to change your assembly from the artifact-with-dependencies descriptorRef to an inline assembly, so that the "exec" version of the jar is built into your Docker image. (Note also that the artifact-with-dependencies was tossing all those redundant dependencies into your image, making it larger than needed.)

```
<assembly>
  <inline>
    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
        <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
        <includes>
          <include>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-exec.jar</include>
        </includes>
      </fileSet>
    </fileSets>      
  </inline>
</assembly>
```